# Word count not showing on posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I thought it might be an issue with a plugin I'm running, but I'm not seeing a word count on any of my posts on WP 4.0. I've deactivated all plugins, and that hasn't fixed me.

Well, not seeing is probably not very accurate - word counts are all 0, even on posts I've written pre-4.0. I'm running roughly latest PHP5.5 and MySQL 5.5 on the server, if that's at all relevant. The database looks fine on the surface, so am I missing something obfious?

Comment: I ran into a bunch of other issues, mostly related to javascript, while trying to troubleshoot this issue. It warranted a reinstall of WordPress. Fixed my javascript issues, but this problem still exists. It only shows up on one site running 4.0. Problem exists in latest IE and Firefox on Windows 7.

Comment: Alright, looks like it may definitely be an issue with the site's javascript. I turn on script debug, I get a word count - but temporarily. It reverts to 0 again if I, say, move to edit a different post or add a new one. If I turn off script debugging, then refresh the page, word count returns. Again, until I edit a different post or add a new one. Then it's back to 0.

Comment: Correction to original post: I'm running latest php 5.4, not 5.5.

Comment: Is word count a default feature of WordPress? I do not seem to recall ever seeing it before. Also, please don't use the comments section as a place to put your train of thoughts. If it is relevant to the question then edit and add it to your question.

Comment: on Word Count I have worked before for post experts. Its inbuilt function [excerpt] you can find this in functions.php

Comment: Is this for the admin area or the front end?  You could very easily edit your theme to include it if it's on the front end, rather than using a plugin.

Comment: @mike... I want it to use for front end users.

Comment: Can you please, suggest me in which section of theme, I can perform these edits. I have no idea, I am pretty much confused.. Thank You

Comment: @dreamyourcareer great, I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've noted that this is to be used on the frontend of the site, so you can achieve it without the use of a plugin.

Place the following code in your `functions.php` file:

```
function word_count() {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    return $word_count;
}
```

You can then use the function `word_count()` in your theme.  `word_count()` returns the word count of the post, so you'll need to echo it out:

```
<?php echo word_count(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank You a lot.. This worked for me. Thanks again for resolving my issue that I was facing from last 2-3 days. :)

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to remove the old plugin so there's no additional overhead.

Comment: Yes, I have removed plugin :)